# If $N$ is a subset of a monoid $(M,\bot ,e)$ with identity element $\epsilon$ with respect $\bot$ then does the equality $\epsilon=e$ holds?

Tags: abstract-algebra, examples-counterexamples, monoid

If $(M,\bot,e)$ is a monoid then it is usually to say that $N$ in $\mathcal P(M)$ is a [submonoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid#Submonoids) of $(M,\bot, e)$ if it is closed under $\bot$ and it contains $e$. So by this definition I suspect that if $(N,\bot)$ is a subgroup with a identity element $\epsilon$ then the equality
$$
\epsilon=e
$$
cannot hold but unfortunately I did not find any counterexample about so that I thought to put a specific question. Could someone help me, please?

Comment: Hello again! I think this has probably been answered somewhere already, but a typical example is "$\Bbb Z$ under multiplication" and the subset just containing $0$. In general $\epsilon$ will always be idempotent, and in fact whenever an element is idempotent, the singleton subset containing that element is a subsemigroup which is isomorphic to the trivial group. Some other examples are given by looking at matrices under multiplication - where you can have a subsemigroup of "matrices of rank at most $2$" or things like that.

Comment: Sorry but I did not understand well: you are claiming that the singleton $\{0\}$ is a counterexample for $(\Bbb Z,\cdot,1)$ since trivially $0\cdot 0$ is $0$, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. There we have $e = 1$ and $\epsilon = 0$, if I've understood what you're asking correctly.

Comment: Perfect: nice and simple counterexample! Obviously if you like you can write and answer and I surely upvoted it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$
\newcommand\Z{\mathbb Z}
$If there is $\epsilon \in M$ which is idempotent ($\epsilon^2 = \epsilon$) then $\{\epsilon\}$ is a monoid with identity $\epsilon$, but moreover so is $\epsilon M\epsilon$. This is particulary used when $M$ is a ring in which case its called a *corner ring*. I'm not sure if "corner monoid" is standard but let's go with that. Note that $\epsilon = 0$ gives us $0M0 = \{0\}$.

For a more concrete example consider the multiplicative monoid $M = \Z/20\Z$. Then $5^2 = 25 = 5$ is idempotent and
$$
  5M5 = 5M = \{0, 5, 10, 15\}
$$
is a monoid that has $5$ as identity.

For a noncommutative example, consider $3{\times}3$ matrices over any ring $R$. The matrix
$$\epsilon = \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
is idempotent and so
$$
  \epsilon M\epsilon = \left\{\begin{pmatrix} a & b & 0 \\ c & d & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix} \;:\; a, b, c, d \in R\right\}
$$
is a monoid with identity $\epsilon$.

---

All subsets of $M$ which are monoids with different identity are submonoids of its corner monoids. This is because if $\epsilon \in M$ is the identity of some $N \subseteq M$ then $\epsilon^2 = \epsilon$ and by virtue of being the identity of $N$ we get
$$
  N = \epsilon N\epsilon \subseteq \epsilon M\epsilon.
$$

Comment: Perfect! nice counterexample: answer upvoted and approved. Thanks very much for your assistance! :-)